# Convert a regex struct in to a string in elixir

Tags: regex, elixir

Is there a simple way to get a string representation of a regex? Passing a regex to `IO.inspect` prints out the string representation so I assume this must be possible in some way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Regex.source/1`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Regex.html#source/1).

> #### Regex.source(regex)
>
> Returns the regex source as a binary.

Demo:

```
iex(1)> Regex.source(~r/[a-z]/)
"[a-z]"
```

Answer (score 1):

Acc. to [Elixir Regex documentation](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Regex.html) you may use:

> [`source(regex)`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Regex.html#source/1)
>   `source(t) :: String.t`
>   Returns the regex source as a binary.
>   [`opts(regex)`](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Regex.html#opts/1) - 
> `opts(t) :: String.t`
>   Returns the regex options as a string.

See [Elixir demo](http://ideone.com/IJRfUJ):

```
rx = ~r/\(cat\d{8} #{"foo"}\)/i
IO.puts Regex.opts(rx)
IO.puts Regex.source(rx)
```

Output:

```
i
\(cat\d{8} foo\)
```

Knowing both the pattern and modifiers, you can base your further actions.